# Jhipster 5.7.2 How to Migrate to mysql from H2 keeping my modifications

Tags: mysql, jhipster, h2

I created a jhipster project by selecting the h2 database option. I have made a lot of changes on my project and I want to switch to a mysql database to keep my data.

So I changed `"devDatabaseType": "h2Disk"`, from the file **yo-rc.json** to `"devDatabaseType": "mysql"`. However when I do the command "jhipster upgrade --force" or "jhipster" I lose all the modifications made on angular or my java project.

How can I migrate my database without losing my changes

***(Update) After Edit :***

```
src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml 
src/test/resources/config/application.yml
Delete **DatabaseConfiguration.java**  
Edit **WebConfigurer.java**, **SecurityConfiguration.java 
navbar.component.html** and **pom.xml**  to remove references to H2
```

I get this error : [stack trace](https://pastebin.com/raw/7rHSQPph)
The complete project with the bug is available here : [project](https://github.com/valentinwmtz/trouvetonprof-aston/tree/migrateMysql)

Comment: You should not have changed 'ddl-auto: none' to 'ddl-auto: create-drop', it's the job of Liquibase to create the database not Hibernate. You also have duplicated Liquibase configuration in DatabaseConfiguration.java and LiquibaseConfiguration.java. You should disable caching in application-dev.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to run `jhipster upgrade` for such a simple change.

- Edit your `src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml` to use mysql, copy datasource properties from `application-prod.yml` but don't set cache properties to true. Same thing for unit tests in `src/test/resources/config/application.yml`
- Empty `DatabaseConfiguration.java` but keep the class for the `@Enable*` class annotations.
- Edit `WebConfigurer.java`, `SecurityConfiguration.java`and `navbar.component.html` to remove references to H2 console
- Edit `pom.xml` or `*.gradle`  to remove dependency on h2

Comment: Thanks @gaël, after doing this I get this error : `connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@1e807f5b marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
` here are the changes I made : [git](https://github.com/valentinwmtz/trouvetonprof-aston/commit/e2160a888de3fbe2a7587dcea0771a49af21b972)

Comment: Please edit your question rather than putting much text in comments, it'll be more readable.Also put full stack trace and give more details