# Migrating database from H2 to MySql in Jhipster

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jhipster

so i am encountring an issue already declared in this Link: [Jhipster 5.7.2 How to Migrate to mysql from H2 keeping my modifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712668/jhipster-5-7-2-how-to-migrate-to-mysql-from-h2-keeping-my-modifications)
i did edit the following files as Gaël Marziou mentioned in his answer :

- rc/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml
- application-prod.yml
- src/test/resources/config/application.yml
- DatabaseConfiguration.java
- WebConfigurer.java, SecurityConfiguration.java and navbar.component.html to remove references to H2 console
- Edit pom.xml to remove dependency on h2.

Then after running the backend with the command: mvn -P-webpack. I get this Error "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure".

stack trace :

```
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::

2020-09-01 00:50:49.224  INFO 17272 --- [  restartedMain] smoothalgo.ZakatReminderApp              : Starting ZakatReminderApp on Nizz with PID 17272 (C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\PFE\another-chance\target\classes started by ACER in C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\PFE\another-chance)
2020-09-01 00:50:49.235 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] smoothalgo.ZakatReminderApp              : Running with Spring Boot v2.2.4.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.3.RELEASE
2020-09-01 00:50:49.241  INFO 17272 --- [  restartedMain] smoothalgo.ZakatReminderApp              : The following profiles are active: dev
2020-09-01 00:50:54.348 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] i.m.c.u.i.logging.InternalLoggerFactory  : Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
2020-09-01 00:50:55.075 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] smoothalgo.config.WebConfigurer          : Registering CORS filter
2020-09-01 00:50:55.153  INFO 17272 --- [  restartedMain] smoothalgo.config.WebConfigurer          : Web application configuration, using profiles: dev
2020-09-01 00:50:55.155  INFO 17272 --- [  restartedMain] smoothalgo.config.WebConfigurer          : Web application fully configured
2020-09-01 00:50:55.548 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByLogin      : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.578 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByEmail      : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.583 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.core.Ehcache-smoothalgo.domain.User  : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.588 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.Authority                 : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.593 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.User.authorities          : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.597 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.BankAccount               : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.617 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.BankAccount.balances      : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.622 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.Ehcache-smoothalgo.domain.Balance  : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.628 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.Ehcache-smoothalgo.domain.Period   : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.633 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.Period.balances           : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.638 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.Ehcache-smoothalgo.domain.Zakat    : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.642 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.Zakat.payments            : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.647 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.Ehcache-smoothalgo.domain.Payment  : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.651 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.Beneficiary               : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.657 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.Beneficiary.payments      : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.660 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.ExtraUser                 : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.664 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.ExtraUser.beneficiarys    : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.668 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.ExtraUser.zakats          : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.674 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.ExtraUser.periods         : Initialize successful.
2020-09-01 00:50:55.705 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] smoothalgo.config.AsyncConfiguration     : Creating Async Task Executor
2020-09-01 00:50:55.739 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] s.config.LiquibaseConfiguration          : Configuring Liquibase
2020-09-01 00:50:58.875 ERROR 17272 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at smoothalgo.ZakatReminderApp.main(ZakatReminderApp.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
        ... 37 common frames omitted

2020-09-01 00:50:58.881 ERROR 17272 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at smoothalgo.ZakatReminderApp.main(ZakatReminderApp.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
        ... 37 common frames omitted

2020-09-01 00:51:02.583 ERROR 17272 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at smoothalgo.ZakatReminderApp.main(ZakatReminderApp.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
        ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
        ... 55 common frames omitted

2020-09-01 00:51:02.591  WARN 17272 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2020-09-01 00:51:04.826 DEBUG 17272 --- [  restartedMain] smoothalgo.security.jwt.TokenProvider    : Using a Base64-encoded JWT secret key
2020-09-01 00:51:11.723  INFO 17272 --- [  restartedMain] smoothalgo.ZakatReminderApp              : Started ZakatReminderApp in 23.851 seconds (JVM running for 25.408)
2020-09-01 00:51:11.736  INFO 17272 --- [  restartedMain] smoothalgo.ZakatReminderApp              :
----------------------------------------------------------
        Application 'zakat_reminder' is running! Access URLs:
        Local:          http://localhost:8080/
        External:       http://192.168.42.204:8080/
        Profile(s):     [dev]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

and that's my github project link : https://github.com/nizarbg96/ZakatProject.git

Comment: Did you start a mysql database which is reachable via localhost:3306, for example via docker(compose)?

Comment: u mean runing docker-compose up  on the "src/main/docker/mysql.yml" file ?
i have started a mysql container with  "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mysql.yml up" and it works fine.

**CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                       PORTS                                              NAMES
17f9e3e9589a        mysql:8.0.19        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute            0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                  docker_zakat_reminder-my**

Comment: You can connect to the running container with the credentials in your application properties?

Comment: great ! connection is done to the container and after adding **allowPublicKeyRetrieval: true** to data-source-proproties in **application-dev.yml** and in  **src/test/resources/config/application.yml**, it works  and liquibase have successfully updated the database. but how to deal with jdbc connection error when running the backend with  mvn -P-webpack

Comment: well i ve just realized that mysql is not an embeded database like H2 database and need to be configured and installed alone, so as mentionned before it works fine now with mysql running in a docker container.

Comment: Yes. Thats why JHipster configures H2 by default for dev/test so you don't need to have an external process to run and test your application.